# ERROR org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Context initialization failed org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

> [RMI TCP Connection(7)-127.0.0.1] ERROR
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Context
>   initialization failed
>       org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private com.springapp.mvc.UserRepository
>   com.springapp.mvc.UserController.userRepository; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:

**User.java**

```
package com.springapp.mvc;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity(name = "account")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Basic
    private String firstName;

    @Basic
    private String lastName;

    @Basic
    private String email;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String name) {
        this.firstName = name;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

**UserRepository.java**

```
package com.springapp.mvc;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
}
```

**UserRepositoryImpl.java**

```
package com.springapp.mvc;

import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.List;

@Component
public class UserRepositoryImpl implements UserRepository{

    public UserRepositoryImpl() {
    }

    @Override
    public <S extends User> S save(S entity) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public User findOne(Long aLong) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean exists(Long aLong) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> findAll() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> findAll(Sort sort) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Page<User> findAll(Pageable pageable) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> findAll(Iterable<Long> longs) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long count() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Long aLong) {

    }

    @Override
    public void delete(User entity) {

    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Iterable<? extends User> entities) {

    }

    @Override
    public void deleteAll() {

    }

    @Override
    public void flush() {

    }

    @Override
    public void deleteInBatch(Iterable<User> entities) {

    }

    @Override
    public void deleteAllInBatch() {

    }

    @Override
    public User getOne(Long aLong) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public <S extends User> S saveAndFlush(S entity) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public <S extends User> List<S> save(Iterable<S> entities) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**UserController.java**

```
package com.springapp.mvc;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;

@Controller
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listUsers(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("user", new User());
        model.addAttribute("users", userRepository.findAll());
        return "users";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult result) {

        userRepository.save(user);

        return "redirect:/";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/delete/{userId}")
    public String deleteUser(@PathVariable("userId") Long userId) {

        userRepository.delete(userRepository.findOne(userId));

        return "redirect:/";
    }   
}
```

**mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans

                  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
                  http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
                  http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.springapp.mvc"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.springapp.mvc"/>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="defaultPersistenceUnit"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

</beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
<web-app version="2.4"
    xmlns="http  ://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http  ://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: Could you please include the complete error output?

Comment: Complete error output here https://www.dropbox.com/s/fmfj8254396vkod/outputlog.txt?dl=0

Comment: It seems that there is a version mismatch, could you include your pom.xml?

Comment: Pom.xml here https://www.dropbox.com/s/1ngn9yx2m3818tq/pom.xml?dl=0

Comment: Patrick, thank you, I update spring version on my pom.xml to 4.1.4 and my app was worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complete stacktrace shows:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.findPropertyForMethod(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/beans/PropertyDescriptor;
```

This issue is caused by the Spring core version used (4.1.1), which has only one parameter for type Method (check [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.1.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/BeanUtils.html#findPropertyForMethod-java.lang.reflect.Method-)).

There is dependencies mismatch, try to change Spring version to 4.1.3 or greater.